# mod_rewrite: match string within URL, which regex to chose?

Tags: regex, apache, web-services, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to use mod_rewrite to capture a string within brackets in my URL and do a redirect.

My URL:

`something?var_a=A&var_b=(B)&var_c=C`

my .httaccess file with the regex:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?.+var_b=\((.*)\)$ somedir/$1 [R]
```

I just would like to capture what's in between the round brackets, so my redirect should look something like this: `somedir/B`

I test my regex at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ but I get no match.

I don't know what I am missing here, even if I try much simpler regexes, e.g. `.+var_b(.*)$` I get no match. Only if my regex was looking for a pattern at the beginning, I get a match, so for example the regex `something(.*)$` works.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)var_b=\((.*?)\)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ somedir/%2? [R]
```

The reason is that RewriteRule does not receive the `?x=y` part of the query. The `%2` variable refers to the pattern from the last `RewriteCond`, while `$2` would refer to the pattern from this `RewriteRule`. The `?` at the end prevents the query part `?x=y` from being automatically appended at the end of the result.

The `(^|&)` and `(&|$)` in the pattern guarantee that `var_b=(B)` is the complete parameter and not a part of it. Without these, the pattern would also match `?xyzvar_b=(B)` or `?var_b=(B)xyz`. With these, it will only match `?var_b=(B)` or `?a=b&var_b=(B)&x=z` etc.

Comment: Thanks! What is the `(^|&)` and `($|&)` for?

Comment: I added this to the answer.