# mod_rewrite: encode only certain matches in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, urlencode

I am trying to rewrite a URL using mod_rewrite and encode a substring in my URL which is between brackets. My URL:

```
http://localhost/something?var_a=A&var_b=(B&2/3&)&var_c=C
```

and my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)\((.*?)\)(.+) 
RewriteRule ^.*$ somedir/%1%2%3? [R,B]
```

so I capture three strings, anything before the brackets, anything within, and anything after.

Result is:

```
somedir/var_a%3dA%26var_b%3dB%262%2f3%26%26var_c%3dC
```

but I would like to encode only the text which was within the brackets of my initial URL, such that

```
somedir/var_a=A&var_b=dB%262%2f3%26&var_c=C
```

The problem seems to be that the `[B]` option decodes the whole string. Is there a way to do this selectively? Also, my solution could only capture an occurrence of brackets once, it would be nice to have this more generic; could someone give me a hint?

Note that this question is related to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909087/mod-rewrite-match-string-within-url-which-regex-to-chose), where I was trying to capture text between brackets.

Comment: are you working with php ?

Comment: no, I am using mod_perl

Comment: I have a solution for you, but I'm not familiar with perl. The solution is passing to your application only one parameter which is the string that goes after `somedir/...`and you can then extract all the data you want from your string

Comment: using the apache request object? I can access the whole string from that and could decode it, but I don't know how to tell the request object to then extract the parameters from the decoded string...

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely tricky for `mod_rewrite` but I took a shot at it. Solution is not pretty as it involves 2 redirects and use of cookies, but it works.

```
RewriteEngine On

# store non bracket query string in cookie while redirecting value in brackets using B flag
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?(var_b=)\(([^)]*)\)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^somedir/ /somedir/%3? [L,CO=QS:%1-%2-%4:%{HTTP_HOST},B,R]

# retrieve value from cookie and use it to construct full URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} QS=([^-]*)-([^-]+)-([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(somedir)/(.*)$ /$1/%1%2$2%3? [L,R,NE]
```

Using these rules when I visit this URL: `http://localhost/something?var_a=A&var_b=(B&2/3&)&var_c=C`

it gets redirected to: `http://localhost/somedir/var_a=A&var_b=B%262%2f3%26&var_c=C`

Comment: Thank you! However, I cannot get it to work, I get redirected to `http://localhost/somedir/B%25262%252f3%2526`, with only variable B.